# I am trying to drop random values from 10*3 matrix and make it to 10 *2 matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

## Original code generating 10*3 matrix

```
random_values = np.round(np.random.normal(mean, std_deviation, (num_rows, num_columns)), 
2)
b_values = np.sort(random_values, axis=1)[:, ::-1]
weights = np.array([0.2, 0.5, 0.3])
y_values = np.round(np.dot(b_values, weights), 2)
```

## Dropping random values from the original matrix

```
def drop_random_value(matrix):
    for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    # Get a random index within the row
    random_index = np.random.randint(matrix.shape[1])
    
    # Set the value at the random index to NaN
    matrix[i, random_index] = np.nan
```

## Drop random values from b_values

```
   drop_random_value(b_values)

   print("Modified b_values:")
   print(b_values)

Expected Output:
[[0.93  0.12 ]
 [0.4   0.4  ]
 [0.64  0.23 ]
 [0.56  0.56 ]
 [0.44  0.41 ]
 [0.55  0.55 ]
 [0.52  0.23 ]
 [0.69  0.69 ]
 [0.62  0.405]
 [0.71  0.53 ]]

Actual Output:[[0.93    nan 0.12 ]
               [  nan 0.4   0.4  ]
               [0.64    nan 0.23 ]
               [0.56  0.56    nan]
               [0.44  0.41    nan]
               [0.55  0.55    nan]
               [  nan 0.52  0.23 ]
               [0.69  0.69    nan]
               [0.62  0.405   nan]
               [  nan 0.71  0.53 ]]
```

Could you please help me in achieving the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
def drop_random_value(matrix):
    for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        random_index = np.random.randint(matrix.shape[1])
        matrix[i, random_index] = np.nan

    return matrix[~np.isnan(matrix)].reshape((matrix.shape[0], matrix.shape[1] - 1))


b_values = drop_random_value(b_values)
print(b_values)
```

---

If `b_values` was:

```py
[[ 0.2  -0.02 -0.09]
 [ 0.08  0.07 -0.1 ]
 [ 0.06  0.05 -0.  ]
 [ 0.25  0.1  -0.06]
 [ 0.08 -0.04 -0.07]
 [-0.03 -0.06 -0.11]
 [ 0.04 -0.02 -0.2 ]
 [-0.04 -0.07 -0.15]
 [ 0.07  0.   -0.03]
 [ 0.05 -0.01 -0.09]]
```

Then after the call:

```
[[-0.02 -0.09]
 [ 0.08  0.07]
 [ 0.06  0.05]
 [ 0.25 -0.06]
 [ 0.08 -0.07]
 [-0.06 -0.11]
 [ 0.04 -0.02]
 [-0.07 -0.15]
 [ 0.07 -0.03]
 [ 0.05 -0.01]]
```